# re-configure php for imagemagic and openjpeg

Tags: php, imagemagick

My PHP scripts cannot read jpeg2000 files, and neither can the imagemagick command line.
I installed Ubuntu 18.04 server from the standard download, it installed imagemagick and PHP for me. Apparently the default installation of Ubuntu does not include the openjpeg libary. I followed the instructions to install this, but imagemagick does not find it. I get the impression that I must re-build imagemagick from the sources, but ubuntu will not let me un-install the current version (6.9.7) because it is a critical system component that many other things depend on (including PHP?).
Is there a way to re-configure PHP to use the new openjpeg library? Do I have to uninstall everything that depends on imagemagik, re-build it and re-install them all? How do I find out what that list of things is?

I tried sudo apt install imagemagick and it said it was installing version 8:6.9.7.4, but when I ask the imagmagick command line aliases, they all say they are still version 6.9.7

I tried sudo apt purge imagemagick and it purged version 8:6.9.7.4 but all the old commands like convert are still there, not purged, and still version 6.9.7

OK, that 8: was a red herring, that was version 6.9.7 again.

I tried following the instructions in the answer to this:
[Upgrade to imagemagick7 and force php to use it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255966/upgrade-to-imagemagick7-and-force-php-to-use-it)
It said it built imagemagick 7.1.0 and if I run sudo convert -version that it what I see, but if i run convert -version (from a non-root account) it still runs 6.9.7. How do I make the new version work for all users? Using sudo convert test.jp2 test.png produces a corrupted png file that cannot be used.

Well, I don't care if the command lines work, my goal is to get PHP working. So I proceeded with the 'Compile and Install PHP imagick:' instructions in that above linked question. Finally, PHP can read jpeg2000 files!

Answer (score 0):

In this question: [Upgrade to imagemagick7 and force php to use it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255966/upgrade-to-imagemagick7-and-force-php-to-use-it) the instructions for installing ImageMagick 7.1.0 by Eduardo Donoso did not get the command line conversions working for all users, but it did update imagick in PHP and now my scripts can read jpeg2000 images!